# Replay does not show the plotcandle results when using a long with security

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code that compute the HA candles. I use the security to make sure I am getting the standard tick information.

```
//@version=5
indicator("HA", overlay=true)
offset = input.int(0,"Offset",options = [-2000,-1500,-1000,-500,-400,-300, -200,-100,0,10,20,30,50,100,150, 200,300,400,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000])
positive = input.color(color.new(#673ab7,0), "Positive" ,inline = "ccc")
negetive = input.color(color.new(#b2b5be,0), "Negetive" ,inline = "ccc")

[closes,opens,lows,highs] = request.security(ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, [close,open,low,high])
var float ha_open = na
ha_close = (opens + highs + lows + closes)/4
ha_open := na(ha_open[1]) ? (opens + closes)/2 : (ha_open[1] + ha_close[1]) / 2
ha_high = math.max(ha_open , highs, ha_close)
ha_low = math.min(ha_open , lows , ha_close)

bar_color = ha_open < ha_close ?positive : negetive
plotcandle(ha_open+offset, ha_high+offset, ha_low+offset, ha_close+offset, title='Title', color = bar_color, wickcolor=bar_color,bordercolor = bar_color )
```

In the normal cases the script works okay, but when I use the replay the results start to crash and it will be like the following image.

[image]
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you using electronic trading hours or regular trading hours?

Comment: It was on ETH
I am in 10 min and ES1!

Comment: Okay, I think I figure it out, the issue can be solved if we use ETH and Dont use B-ADJ, using RTH or activating B-ADJ can cause the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this issue with using ETH time and dont using B-ADJ